# Como detectar Left e Top atuais do Form ao arrastar (no Delphi)?

Tags: delphi

Preciso detectar o valor de Left e Top do Form (em tempo real) ao arrastar e exibir os valores em SpinEdits (SEdtX e SEdtY).

Estou utilizando o código abaixo, porém sem sucesso:

```
 private
   { Private declarations }
   procedure WMNCHitTest(var M: TWMNCHitTest);
```

Procedimento:

```
procedure TFrmMain.WMNCHitTest(var M: TWMNCHitTest);
begin
 inherited;
    if M.Result = htCaption then
    //Ao arrastar o Form atualiza os SpinEdits
    SEdtX.Value := FrmMain.Left;
    SEdtY.Value := FrmMain.Top;
end;
```

O que devo alterar?

Comment: Tentei por no MouseDown do Form, mas não funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na declaração do método. Este espera uma [mensagem do sistema operacional](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/Messages_(Delphi)) para dispará-lo. Faltou declarar qual mensagem ele está esperando, a declaração correta seria:

```
procedure WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;
```

Atualização:

A mensagem mais adequada para este fim é a `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`, esta captura em tempo real o movimento da tela.

```
procedure WMPosChanging(var Msg: TWmWindowPosChanging); message WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING;
```

Comment: Como eu declaro essa procedure no OnMouseDown?

Comment: @lukkicode, você não precisa chamar este procedimento em nenhum evento, o próprio sistema operacional que vai dispara-lo através de mensagens. Basta fazer a declaração deste método na classe do form que você deseja fazer sua verificação e fazer as tratativas necessárias no mesmo método.

Comment: Muito obrigado.